# How to control a presentation on computer using iPad?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, ipad, microsoft-office-2013, presentations, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am presenting something to a small audience of 50+ people. I have a projector to which I will connect my laptop.

Instead of navigating the presentation (Microsoft PowerPoint) on the computer and reading the presenter's notes, is there a way to do that from an iPad?

My iPad and computer can connect using Bluetooth. If needed, I can connect both to Internet streaming from my phone.

---

My equipment is:

- Presentation in Microsoft Office 2013
- Laptop (Dell Inspiron, Intel i3) with Windows 8.1
- iPad (Air 2) with iOS 8.3

---

**P.S.:** *Please note that I am more interested in solutions which don't require spending money, as I already spent a lot on the iPad and laptop.*

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that there are apps on the appstore that accomplish this. [Here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slideshow-remote-for-powerpoint/id328556878?mt=8) is an example of one such app, though there seem to be several choices (some of which may be free).

Googling "control powerpoint with ipad" returned many results and apps that accomplish exactly what you are asking.

Comment: +1 Yes, I'm sure there are many similar apps, but there is one from Microsoft as well.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, I didn't see that in my research

Comment: I just realised that the iOS version is another app for Remote Desktop.  Office Remote is currently only available on Windows Phone and Android, although the Android version only came out recently, so there may be an iOS version soon.